# How to program button click event inside the repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET. I added a button inside the repeater. When theruser clicks the button, a specific row value should be displayed on the label outside the repeater. This is the design of that I want to implement.

[image]

Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt3" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>  
<h3>   <%#Eval("name") %>  </h3>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Details"/> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

C#:

```cs
public void Getuser() {
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString)) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from message  where emailid= '" + Session["un"].ToString() + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0][0] != string.Empty) {
            rpt3.DataSource = dt;
            rpt3.DataBind();
        } else {
            rpt3.DataSource = null;
            rpt3.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be many ways, you can add your click event on you page load. simply check the items inside repeater and set the button click event like:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in rpt3.Items)
     {
         Button btn = rptItem .FindControl("btnShowLabel") as Button;
         btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
     }
```

and then you can perform you task on click event like:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rptItem = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        Label lb = (Label)rptItem.FindControl("lbShowing");
        lb.Text = "Showing you text here";
    }
```

2. by Command name also on your button and then repeater ItemCommand event.

code behind:

```
 protected void rp3_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "show")
    {
    }
  }
```

Front

Comment: ok,but i want to display database table row value related to row button click.like if we click on the button it will display user details on the label related to that row.

Comment: yes, you can set datatabase id on button as command argument and then simply pass that commandargument value to your database logic which will return you only that user info. Command Argument you set on attribute of button CommandArgument="121"

Comment: Could you please give me some example that coding??

Comment: i am selecting 1st one sir